# Angular material datepicker position is wrong except on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular-material and `md-datepicker` in my project.

I'm having a form, containing several inputs and `<md-datepicker>` and the problem is that the position of the datepickers (the calendar, not the initial input) is wrong except for the first one if I'm not using Google Chrome.

The position seems to be correct if all the `<md-datepicker>` are at the top of the page next to each other, but as soon as we need to scroll down a bit, the positioning is failing.

Here is a codepen where you can see the issue on Firefox : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjGPGZ?editors=101

Just scroll down and try to use the datepickers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gianni pointed out, it has been Fixed by :
https://github.com/angular/material/commit/d423a65600cb6dc2638c91882b38be2dfea965f8

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your codepen on chrome, firefox and safari. Everything worked fine, I got no issues.

Comment: You managed to display the last datepickers in the bottom of the pages (after scrolling down) correctly at the proper position under Firefox ? I don't

Comment: Yes, even the last one. I have Firefox 42.0 on a Mac

Comment: Well it's not working on 42.0 or 44.0a2 Developer Edition  on Windows

Comment: The same happen to me(Firefox 42 on Win 7 64bit). It seems that the position of the Calendar is absolute based on the browser window dimensions and not based on the page dimensions. If I change the position of the calendar to "fixed" by using the deleloper tools  it shows well. Using Chrome there are no problems. Did you find a solution? EDIT: Seems that is a resolved issue https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5758

Comment: I am using the angular material version 1.0.1. can you explain me what changes I should do in angular.material.min.js to fix this issue?