# Angular Material Datepicker opening position is wrong in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

The md-datepicker element from Angular Material is opening at the wrong calendar position (eg a month or two in the future) from the default date, when viewed in Chrome. Similarly, if the years view is selected it opens a year or two from the default date.

This post ([Angular material datepicker position is wrong except on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735444/angular-material-datepicker-position-is-wrong-except-on-chrome)) asks the reverse of this question, strangely, saying that it works in Chrome but is broken in OTHER browsers. Responses to that question indicate that it has been fixed for FireFox, IE and Safari.

Tested on both Chrome desktop and Android with same (broken) result.

Here are two separate Codepen repositories showing the problem.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjGPGZ?editors=101

http://codepen.io/DionOrr/pen/pNmQzb

Code from the second link is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p>Inside md-input-container
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate1" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate2" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate3" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate4" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate5" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate6" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate7" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
      <br>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Test datepicker</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate8" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
    </p>
    <p>Not inside md-input-container
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate9" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate10" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate11" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate12" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate13" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate14" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate15" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <br>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="testdate16" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-aria.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-messages.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
    app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.testdate1 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate2 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate3 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate4 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate5 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate6 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate7 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate8 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate9 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate10 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate11 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate12 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate13 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate14 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate15 = new Date();
      $scope.testdate16 = new Date();
    });
</script>
```

Please open them on Chrome (either desktop or mobile), particularly trying the datepickers lower down the page.

This question (github.com/angular/material/issues/5055) alludes to a similar problem with the Angular Material datepicker and attributes it to being incorrectly placed in an md-input-container. But the second codepen link above specifically shows that the problem recurs whether or not the datepicker is inside a md-input-container, thus ruling out that answer in this case.

Is there a simple fix?

Comment: It's opening at the correct position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be an issue on Chrome. See [Issue #10144](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10144). I've submitted [Pull Request #10177](https://github.com/angular/material/pull/10177) to fix the issue, but it has yet to be merged.

Here is your CodePen fixed: [Basic Usage Fixed](http://codepen.io/phillypham/pen/yVWGEG).

I added a dependency on my branch:

```
https://rawgit.com/ppham27/material/dist/dist/angular-material.js
```

and updated the version of Angular to 1.5.9 and used the new stylesheet, too.

This is a temporary fix of course. A permanent fix would require waiting for the pull request to go through. I'm unsure if there is any way to speed up the process.